Consulta usando pandas en python
estoy usando la base de datos pubs, muy conocida para hacer practicas con base de datos, tengo que conseguir las ganancias por autor, en vase a algunos parametros que le estoy pasando con una consulta donde meto los datos que necesito, ya que todas las operaciones y reglas debo manejarlas con la libreria pandas, hasta ahora tengo lo siguiente
import mysql.connector
import pandas as pd

# Conexión a la base de datos MySQL
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="",
    database="pubs"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

# Consulta SQL para obtener los datos necesarios
consulta = """
select authors.au_id,titles.title,titles.title_id, authors.au_fname,sales.qty,titles.price,IFNULL(titleauthor.royaltyper, 0) as royaltyper
from titles
left join titleauthor on titles.title_id = titleauthor.title_id
left join authors on titleauthor.au_id = authors.au_id
left join sales on titleauthor.title_id = sales.title_id
"""

# Ejecutar la consulta
mycursor.execute(consulta)
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()


# Obtener los nombres de las columnas
column_names = [i[0] for i in mycursor.description]

# Crear un DataFrame de Pandas con los resultados de la consulta
pan = pd.DataFrame(myresult, columns=column_names)

# Convertir las columnas 'qty', 'price' y 'royaltyper' a tipo float
pan['qty'] = pan['qty'].astype(float)
pan['price'] = pan['price'].astype(float)
pan['royaltyper'] = pan['royaltyper'].astype(float)

# Calcular las ganancias
pan['ganancias'] = pan['qty'] * pan['price'] * (pan['royaltyper'] / 100)

# Agrupar las ganancias por autor y sumar las ganancias
ganancias_por_autor = pan.groupby(['au_id','au_fname'])['ganancias'].sum().reset_index()


# Imprimir el resultado final
print("Ganancias por autor:")
print(ganancias_por_autor)

# Cerrar el cursor y la conexión a la base de datos
mycursor.close()
mydb.close()

la cuestion aqui es que necesito sacar lo que me falta, es decir, algunos libros que se vendieron y no tienen autor, o regalias que no estan del todo completas porque no se le asignaron a algun autor, por ello son perdidas,y es lo que no se como manejarlo, en la consulta que hice en sql tengo lo siguiente, lo cual si me da la solucion a lo que necesito, pero no se como manejarlo dentro de python con pandas
SELECT 
    ta.au_id AS ID,
    au.au_lname AS Apellido,
    au.au_fname AS Nombre,
    SUM(t.price * s.qty * (ta.royaltyper/100)) AS TotalGanancias
FROM 
    titleauthor AS ta
INNER JOIN 
    titles AS t ON ta.title_id = t.title_id
INNER JOIN 
    sales AS s ON t.title_id = s.title_id
INNER JOIN 
    authors AS au ON ta.au_id = au.au_id
GROUP BY 
    ta.au_id, au.au_lname, au.au_fname
UNION ALL
SELECT "NA","Desconocido", "Desconocido", SUM(s.qty*faltante.price*(royal/100)) as Desvio
    FROM sales as s 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT t.title, t.title_id, 100 - IFNULL(SUM(royaltyper),0) AS royal, t.price
    FROM  titles AS t 
    LEFT JOIN 
        titleauthor AS ta ON ta.title_id = t.title_id
    GROUP BY t.title_id
    HAVING royal > 0 
) AS faltante ON s.title_id = faltante.title_id;

